# Unable to launch a python node using rosrun in ROS-Noetic (Ubuntu20)

Tags: ros, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

COMMAND:

```
rosrun my_robot_tutorial robot_news_radio_transmitter.py   //python publisher node
rosrun my_robot_tutorial smartphone.py    //python subscriber node
```

ERROR:

```
/opt/ros/noetic/bin/rosrun: /home/rishav/catkin_ws/src/my_robot_tutorials/scripts/smartphone.py: **usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**
/opt/ros/noetic/bin/rosrun: line 150: /home/rishav/catkin_ws/src/my_robot_tutorials/scripts/smartphone.py: Success
```

FILE CONTENT OF smartphone.py:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String 


def callback_receive_radio_data(msg):
    rospy.loginfo("Message received : ")
    rospy.loginfo(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('smartphone')

    sub = rospy.Subscriber("/robot_news_radio", String, callback_receive_radio_data)


    rospy.spin()
```

ISSUE:

This error occurred when I tried to launch the python subscriber node.
please give me a solution

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402829/unable-to-launch-a-python-node-using-rosrun-in-ros-noetic-(ubuntu20)/) by [Ris](https://answers.ros.org/users/109026/ris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-24**:
Could you please refrain from using CAPITALS everywhere?

I've already removed quite a few (changed them to regular title case), please keep it in mind for next time.

**Comment by [Ris](https://answers.ros.org/users/109026/ris/) on 2022-06-24**:
yeah sure, I will keep that noted the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> FILE CONTENT OF smartphone.py:
>
> ```
> #!usr/bin/env python3
> ```

this is not a correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (and technically also not a ROS problem).

The first line should read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

note the first `/`, which is important.

Without it, the path is relative to the *current working directory*, which for `roslaunch` would be `$ROS_HOME`. There most likely isn't an `env` binary in `/home/rishav/.ros/usr/bin`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ris](https://answers.ros.org/users/109026/ris/) on 2022-06-24**:
Thank you for helping me out. This was a fundamental error which I committed. Thanks again for your time and such a great explanation.